# What RBF policy will be default on SegWit v1 nodes?

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, segregated-witness, bitcoin-core-development, replace-by-fee

What RBF node policy will be applied by default in order for a SegWit v1 transaction to relay when encountered. Full RBF, or Opt-in RBF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there are currently no formal proposals to introduce Full RBF. Therefore, I'm expecting that the default behavior of upcoming nodes will remain to forward and create transactions according to the rules specified in [BIP125, Opt-in RBF](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0125.mediawiki).